# generic method <T> in Java

Tags: java, generics

The next method is generic,but I just wanna know what is the Usefulness of `<T>` ?, I mean the `<T>` who is next to static and before to void. What happen if I don't write it in my method?.

```
public static <T> void nameMethod(BinaryTreeNode<T> t){
     /*do something
         .
         .
     */
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: <T> lets your method to be whats called generic that is it can return any type of Object. a tutorial on java generics will clear your doubt

Comment: I know that in some cases, the code doesn't compile, but I don't know why, I just know that I have to write it, but I wanna know why.

Comment: In what cases would the code not compile, and what compiler error is given?

Comment: Declaring a type there makes the method generic. If you don't declare the type there, that means the method isn't generic. You don't *have to* write it unless you want the method to be generic. Because writing it makes the method generic. Because that's the syntax that the Java language designers came up with for you to express that you want a method to be generic. If you don't declare it there then the method won't be generic because you haven't specified that it should be generic.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look to a Java tutorial before asking here.

Comment: thanks for the answers, but I know that is generic,I always write a method like public void something(){}; or public static void something(){}; but in this case the generic is before to void, what is the Usefulness of that ?

Comment: Because that's where you define `T`. Just like anywhere else in Java, if you use something, it has to be defined somewhere.

Comment: Chris Martin said it clearly: "If you don't declare the type there, that means the method isn't generic. You don't _have to_ write it unless you want the method to be generic."

Comment: Close vote because this question shows no effort on searching and finding the answer before posting on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<T>` defines a type parameter for the whole context of the method. As far as I can tell, in this particular case, it would indeed be equivalent to

```
public static void nameMethod(BinaryTreeNode<?> t) {
```

However, if you're returning a type `T`, or if you have more than one parameter with the same generic type, you need to declare the type parameter so the compiler has a reference point to identify the type. For example:

```
public static <T> List<T> mergeSort(List<T> l1, List<T> l2) {
    //...
}
```

The `<T>` parameter tells the compiler that both `List`s being passed as well as the `List` returned must be of the same generic type.

This is even more useful when we can declare additional information about `T`:

```
public static <T extends Number> List<T> asList(T... numbers) {
    //build list with Number-specific logic...
}
```

**EDIT:** I was incorrect about my first point. Even without additional parameters or a return type, there may be a use in declaring `<T>`. I'll provide a simple example using a `List`, since I'm not familiar with this `BinaryTreeNode`.

```
public static <T> void duplicateFirstElement(List<T> l) {
    T elm = l.get(0);
    l.add(elm);
}
```

If we were to remove the type parameter and declare the parameter as `List<?>`, there would be no way to retain the generic type while interacting with the list.