# What's the difference between wildcard and 'T'?

Tags: java

```
    public <? extends Animal> void takeThing(ArrayList<?> list)
    public <T extends Animal> void takeThing(ArrayList<T> list)
```

Why this statement is wrong? I mean why the `?` can't be used in the front? But `T` can. What is the difference?

Possible duplicate "[When to use wildcards in Java Generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707340/when-to-use-wildcards-in-java-generics)"

Here is an answer for this question.But I don't get what this mean.
"if you say void then there is no return type. if you specify then there is a return type. i didn't know that you can specify to have return type or no return type."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24113942/1553851 - Read the edit.

Answer (score 5):

Writing `<T extends Animal>` *binds* the type name `T`, so that it can be referred to later in the definition (including in the parameter list).

If you wrote `<? extends Animal>`, then you did not name the type. Therefore, you cannot refer to it later. You can't refer to it as `?` later because that could be ambiguous (what if you had two type parameters?).

Java forbids you from writing `public <?> ...` because such a declaration is useless (the type parameter is not named so it cannot be used).

Answer (score 5):

```
public void takeThing(ArrayList<? extends Animal> list)
```

means "do something with a list of *any* subclass of `Animal`".

```
public <T extends Animal> void takeThing(ArrayList<T> list)
```

means "do something with a list of *some particular* subclass (A.K.A. `T`) of `Animal`".

If I call `list.get()` on the first method, all I know about the returned type is that it extends `Animal`. On the second method, if I had another instance of `List<T>`, I know that whatever type `T` is, both lists would accept the same type.

To take it even further, if I say

```
Animal animal = list.get(0);
```

I can no longer say

```
list.add(animal);
```

even on the very same list, because we don't have a reference to the generic subtype. If however, I declare a `List<T>` where `<T extends Animal>`, I can now say

```
T animal = list.get(0);
list.add(animal);
```

because we know that `list` expects elements of type `T`.